# this question is similar to the another, but im trying to make it so when you click a part, it deletes it

Tags: lua, roblox

```
while true do
    wait(1)
    local randomnumber = math.random(18,150)
    local x  = math.random(1,50)
    local Pointgiver = game.ReplicatedStorage.Points:Clone()
    Pointgiver.Parent = game.Workspace
    Pointgiver.Position = Vector3.new(randomnumber,0.5,x)
    Pointgiver.Transparency = 0
end
local pointgiver = game.Workspace:WaitForChild("Points")
pointgiver.ClickDetector.Mousetouch:Connect(function()
    pointgiver:Destroy()
end)
```

as you see, im using a waitforchild function which waits for a part to spawn and doesnt give errors thats like "There is no part named "Points" "
but it wont destroy it, sorry if that didnt make sense

Answer (score 0):

`ClickDetector` has no function named `Mousetouch`, instead, you should be using `MouseClick` which fires whenever the player clicks the respective `Part`. Also your code which listens for the `ClickDetector.MouseClick` is after the `while loop` and as such, it will never run as you keep calling the `while loop` repeatedly, and never break out of it.

```
while true do
    task.wait(1)

    local randomnumber = math.random(18,150)
    local x  = math.random(1,50)

    local Pointgiver = game.ReplicatedStorage.Points:Clone()
    Pointgiver.Position = Vector3.new(randomnumber,0.5,x)
    Pointgiver.Transparency = 0
    PointGiver.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
       PointGiver:Destroy()
    end)
    Pointgiver.Parent = game.Workspace
end
```

Comment: the more you learn

Comment: well, did this solve your issue?